# Why does this code work on Python 3.6 but not on Python 3.7?

Tags: python, recursion, stack-overflow

In `script.py`:

```
def f(n, memo={0:0, 1:1}):
    if n not in memo:
        memo[n] = sum(f(n - i) for i in [1, 2])
    return memo[n]

print(f(400))
```

`python3.6 script.py` correctly prints `f(400)`, but with `python3.7 script.py` it stack overflows. The recursion limit is reached at `f(501)` in 3.6 and at `f(334)` in 3.7.

What changed between Python 3.6 and 3.7 that caused the maximum recursion depth to be exceeded earlier by this code?

Comment: Works with IPython based on Python 3.9.16, but not with ordinary Python 3.9.16 :|... Actually, if I first do print(f(100)), then afterwards works also with f(400). Really strange behaviour.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75973613/can-you-explain-this-difference-of-depth-recursion-in-python-using-those-seeming/75974020?

Comment: @Samwise Yeah, it's a follow-on from that

Comment: @msi_gerva Doing `f(100)` first pre-populates the shared cache without hitting the stack limit, reducing the recursion depth of the subsequent call to `f(400)`.

Comment: What's the minimum value of `n` required to trigger the `RecursionError` in each version? I'm not sure *how* this would be responsible, but the 3.7 was the first version of (C)Python with the new key-order-preserving implementation of `dict`.

Comment: Partial duplicate: [Why Python raises RecursionError before it exceeds the real recursion limit?](/q/55560258/4518341) That still leaves the question of why the behaviour changed in 3.7.

Comment: On that note, maybe people are downvoting because you're asking about an outdated Python version? Doesn't make much sense, but just a guess.

Comment: It's a good question, because you could consider this a regression (even if only one that took a while to notice) in the stack being effective 33% shorter in some unknown circumstance.

Comment: Try [this](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZA7DsIwDIb3nMJjKlQJNorUkQuwog6lTSACnMp1pPYsLF3gThyCO4D7oPVm___n1-NVtXzx2HXPwDbevj-lsWA1RjsFvyDDgRAQciyhDndttYvAegIHDuGI8SaLlBJIVMd_rg43hhTWfSpAI4DjQV94Vik0y1lDWSlhUBjK8Wx0kiRjb6Z2biKr9olpClMxHEwRqHYe90SeZl9FDnnySpzI5Nfh6PH26Qdf) in both versions. Minified demo, selfmade `sum`, and automatic limit search. The selfmade-sum seems to make the difference, drops the limit to 333 for Python 3.6 in my testing [here](https://www.jdoodle.com/python3-programming-online/). So looks like something about `sum` changed. But I don't know how to look further...

Comment: @chepner older Python versions did not handle the recursion counter correctly but the bugfix was never backported to 3.6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some git bisecting between Python 3.6.0b1 and Python 3.7.0a1 I found [bpo bug #29306](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/73492) (git commits [7399a05](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/7399a05965162f46ca00b5453a59f71fdb5851f1), [620580f](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/620580f280e3fe6583afee43580ef907b228add3)), which identified some bugs with the recursion depth counting.

Originally, Victor Stinner reported that he was unsure that some new internal API functions for optimised calls (part of the [reported call overhead optimisations](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#optimizations)) were handling the recursion counter properly, but after further discussion it was decided that the problem was more general and that all calls to C functions need to handle the recursion counter too.

A simple test script is included in the linked issue that demonstrates that there are issues with recursion counting in older Python versions too; the script depends on a special extension module that is part of the development tree. However, even though Python versions 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6 were shown to be affected the changes were never back-ported. I'm guessing that because those versions didn't receive the call overhead optimisations backporting was going to be a lot of work.  I also can’t find an entry for this change in the [Python changelog](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/changelog.html#changelog), perhaps because Victor regarded this as part of the optimisation work.

The changes mean that `sum()` and other built-in functions now count against the recursive call limit where they didn’t before.